# Multiplication of vectors in two loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, matrix, multiplication

I want to multiply two vectors to produce a matrix.

I have a vector 1*m and another 1*n which are in my case V (1*71) and I (1*315). The other vectors have same length as I.

**I want to multiply every value of I with all values of V and have the answer in a matrix where every row or column of new matrix is `I(t).*V`**

Ir and Temp are vectors with the size of 1*315 and all the variables have the same length and T is 315.

The other parameters that you see in the code are constant values.

This is the code :

```
function [I] = solar2diodedyn( Ir,time,Temp )

V = 0:0.01:0.7; %open circuit voltage of one cell in V.

for t=1:time;

    T(t)= Temp(t)+273; 
    Vt(t)=(k*T(t))/q; 
    Iph(t) = Isc_cell*(Ir(t)/1000)*(1+(T_co*(Temp(t)-25)));
    I0(t)=Is1*((T(t)/Tmeas)^(3/n1))*exp(Eg*((T(t)/Tmeas)-1)/(n1*Vt(t)));
    I02(t)=Is2*((T(t)/Tmeas)^(3/n2))*exp(Eg*((T(t)/Tmeas)-1)/(n2*Vt(t)));
    I(t) = zeros(size(t));
    i=length(V);

    for x=1:i
    I(t) = Iph(t) - I0(t)*(exp((V(x)+I(t)*Rs)/(n1*Vt(t)))-1)-I02(t)*(exp((V(x)+I(t)*Rs)/(n2*Vt(t)))-1)-((V(x)+I(t)*Rs)/Rsh);
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two vectors `x` (of size 1-by-`n`) and `y` (of size 1-by-`m`) and you want a matrix `M` of size `n`-by-`m` such that `M(i,j) = x(i) * y(j)` then you are trying to compute the [**outer product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of `x` and `y`.
This can be done easily with matlab

```
>> M = x.' * y;
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Shai.
I am sorry that I cannot vote for you while I am new and my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: @Shai +1, specially for using `.'` and not `'` :-)